# Supplying credentials in a UNC Path

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I am in support of a database driven windows application wherein the data may come from local or remote system (depending on some configuration files).

Currently MS ACCESS Database is being used.

Application runs smoothly when connected to local database.

But when trying to connect to a remote PC Which is password protected,i am getting the

following error

```
"The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '\\\XXX.XXX.X.X \ YYYY \ ZZZ.mdb'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.
```

i am providing the credentials for database in the  connection string as below.

```
pConObj.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & pAppPath & "\zzzz.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=ppp"
```

**The Remote database resides in a shared folder in remote pc which has read/write permissions for everyone user group**

following is the format of remote path (pAppPath  VALUE in above connection string)

\REMOTE IP ADDRESS\SHARE FOLDER NAME

Please let me know how can i supply remote pc credentials?? or is there anything i am missing here.

**PS:If the remote pc do not have user name and password i am able to connect to remote dabase.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Security wise approach:

1. You need to connect with a user that has access to the remote pc.
2. Assign the user you are connecting with both Share permissions and security permissions on the shared folder.

Not good for security approach:

Assigning Full control permissions for Everyone is not good for security reasons. But if you prefer so, just verify that you allowed full control permissions on folder security and folder share permissions.

Comment: ,Can you let me know how to include user credentials in the connection string i have shown above (i repeat,not database credential which is already included)?

Comment: @ramu: try first assigning full control security permissions for Everyone on the shared folder. Just to see if its solves the issue.

Comment: ,I already tried with full control permission on shared folder but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it working now.

What i learnt from microsoft articles is whenever we try to access resources on a remote

computer,corresponding network connections are mapped to Guest account on the remote pc.

So,in my case guest account was not added in the list of allowed users for the shared folder.

I added the guest account in permissions list and it worked.:-)